# mysql_connect (not working with php file)

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Keep getting same error message
(Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in /home/content/00/7882800/html/Connections/dueslogin.php on line 27
Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.)

```
 <?php
        //Variables for connecting to your database.
        //These variable values come from your hosting account.
        $hostname = "TarHeelsDues.db.7882800.hostedresource.com";
        $username = "TarHeelsDues";
        $dbname = "TarHeelsDues";

        //These variable values need to be changed by you before deploying
        $password = "************";
        $usertable = "DuesLogin";
        $yourfield = "your_field";

        //Connecting to your database
        mysql_connect($hostname, $dbname, $password) OR DIE ("Unable to 
        connect to database! Please try again later.");
        mysql_select_db($TarHeelsDues);

        //Fetching from your database table.
        $query = "SELECT * FROM $usertable";
        $result = mysql_query($query);

        if ($result) {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                $name = $row["$yourfield"];
                echo "Name: $name<br>";
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Check out http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: Also please note that the `mysql_xxx()` functions are obsolete. Please don't use them for writing new code. (The PHP manual page linked by @VadimAshikhman above has a big red box warning of this). You should instead use the `mysqli_xxx()` functions or the PDO library. See http://www.phptherightway.com/#databases for more info.

Comment: by the way -- I hope that usename/password you've quoted in the question aren't real!?! If they are, you need to go and change your password **right now**, because you've told the whole world what your password is.

Answer (score 3):

change the mysql_connect line to

```
mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) OR DIE ("Unable to 
    connect to database! Please try again later.");

mysql_select_db($dbname);
```

Answer (score 1):

A little mistake on there, you have to use $username not $dbname in mysql_connect.

```
 mysql_connect($hostname, $username , $password) OR DIE ("Unable to 
        connect to database! Please try again later.");
        mysql_select_db($TarHeelsDues);
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax should be like this:-

mysql_connect($hostname, $username , $password) OR die ("Unable to connect with the server");
mysql_select_db($TarHeelsDues) or die('Cannot connect with the database!');